# Converting strings of the form "1.34e5" to real numbers?

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation

`ToExpresssion` doesn't understand real numbers of the form `"1.34e5"`. How do I convert the string `"1.34e5"` to a real number in Mathematica?

Comment: I think this question is ill-posed. _Mathematica_ does not normally produce numeric strings of the form in question. Therefore, it seems reasonable to presume the source of the string is external. Should that be the case, then the conversion would be best handled during import. However, becko gives us no information about the source, essentially prohibiting the use of _Mathematica_;s import mechanisms to solve the problem.

Comment: `ImportString["1.34e5", "Table"][[1, 1]]`

Comment: `ImportString["1.34e5", "JSON"]`

Comment: @RunnyKine - maybe its a duplicate, but this question should remain opened for a while (there are many new users like myself).

Comment: @m_goldberg The source is a file containing rows of numbers. All rows are not of the same size, so it is not a matrix (therefore `Import` with option `"Table"` doesn't work). If that's relevant I can add it to the question.

Comment: @m_goldberg However, the question as stated, is a valid question.

Comment: @m_goldberg: AH! +1 on the JSON use, had not thought of that!

Comment: The fact that there is an external file and the format of the data in that file are both relevant. Pleas add a small sample from your data file to the question. The answer you are seeking will most likely involve `Import`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly the simplest solution is

```
ImportString["1.34e5", "JSON"]
```

> ```
> 134000.
> ```

References:

> [JSON](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JSON.html)
>   [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: It is short, yes, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @eldo. Added references you might want to look at

Comment: @m_goldberg Your first link got removed.

Comment: @Saturisk. Thanks for pointing out the broken link. I have repaired it.